# Posting vulnerablity of an operating system

Tags: java, android, c++, operating-system

How can one file/post vulnerability found in Android OS or any other OS/software? I have been searching on internet but may be I don't know the specific term to search with or there is no centeralized place for it.

Regards

Comment: Did you consider making a bug report?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch where can I do that? Kindly excuse my ignorance in this matter

Comment: @user2498079 https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Comment: Ask the provider of your operating system or software. Are you sure to know exactly what precise software component has a vulnerability?

Comment: @ShivamVerma I have checked it out already, there is not place for security bugs report

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes.

Comment: @user2498079: Yes there is. Choose "Bug in the software" (instead of "device" or "feature request"), then choose the template "security bug report". ...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/security.html#issue